# Undefined index: hook_suffix

Tags: wp-list-table

I am getting `"Undefined index: hook_suffix"` error in Wordpress while trying to execute the below. Here `$class_name` extends MyRegularClass and MyRegularClass extends `WP_List_Table`. Please help.

```
$tab_name = substr($tab_name,strlen($wpdb->prefix));
if (class_exists($tab_name.'_class')){
    $class_name = $tab_name.'_class';
    $obj = new $class_name();
} else {
    $obj = new MyRegularClass($tab_name);
}
```

Update: Here I am trying to display a table content in a page(in stead of adding that to a menu) using WP List Table. The issue seems to be due to calling display() before it gets a screen.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined#4261200). It provides a description of what creates "Undefined index" errors. Basically, you need to check the types of $tab_name and $class_name prior to passing them as parameters to objects. Ensure they have values, and those values are appropriate data types.